# In TornadoFX, how can I make one Property change when other properties are changed?

Tags: java, javafx, properties, kotlin, tornadofx

For example, I want to do this: I have a StringProperty, and it is a combination of an IntegerProperty and anoter StringProperty, like this:

- StringProperty A = "foo"
- IntegerProperty B = 3
- resulting StringProperty C = "foo 3"

How can I "bind" properties so that the C changes when either A or B are changed? (Note that I don't want to react to changes made to C)

I tried using `stringBinding()` method, but it is unclear to me how this method works exactly, and the documentation about it is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringBinding` is what you want. The first argument will become `this` inside the calculation block, and if `this` is an observable value, it will be added as a dependency used to calculate when the string binding should be reevaluated. The rest of the parameters (only `b` here) are added as re-evaluation dependencies as well.

If you do `stringBinding(a, b) { "${a.value} ${b.value}" }`, you have created a string binding that will update whenever either `a` or `b` changes. Since `this` is `a` in the above example, you could also have written in `stringBinding(a, b) { "${this.value} ${b.value}" }` but I don't think that makes it any clearer :)

The reason we decided to make the first element `this` is made more apparent by the following example:

`val sizeDescription = bind(items) { "$size elements in list" }`

Here you don't need to reference the `items` again to get to it's `size` property.

Comment: I think you need either `stringBinding(a, b) { "${a.get()} ${b.get()}" }` or `stringBinding(a, b) { "$(a.value) ${b.value}" }`. JavaFX properties show more than just their value with the default `toString()`.